# Creating a comment system with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

My body is layed out as such:

```
<body class="container" ng-controller="ArticleController as data">
<div class="dataholder" ng-repeat="cd in data.datas">
  <h1 class="title">
    {{cd.name}}<p class="date" ng-show="cd.date.length>0"> @ {{cd.date}}</p>

  </h1>
  <h3 class="description">{{cd.description}}</h3>
  <!-- Comment placement -->
  <div class="commentInput">
  <input class="commentbox" ng-show="cd.commentable==true" type="text" placeholder='Comment on this'>
  <button ng-show="cd.commentable==true" class="button">Post</button>
  </div> 
  <div ng-repeat="comment in cd.comments" ng-show="cd.commentable==true" class="commentdiv">
  <h5>
    {{comment.name}}: <p class="comment">{{comment.text}}<p>
  </h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've imported: * AngularJS, * Firebase, * AngularFire.

I've searched quite a lot and have not found a way to make it able to post data to the firebase from within the ng-repeat enabled div. I want this for a comment system. I would want to do something like:

```
onclick='thisref.push( <text from the input in my body> )'
```

In my button.

### But I have no idea how to:

- Let the code know which ref to use depending on what ng-repeat position it is.
- Use the value from the input.

Excuse my bad code.
I'm quite new to web-design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is adding a method to the `$scope` in my controller:

```
$scope.addCard = function(state) {
    var auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(new Firebase(FBURL));
    auth.$getCurrentUser().then(function(user) {
        var card = { title: 'Card '+(cards.length+1), created_by: user.username, created_at: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP, state: state };
        cards.$add(card);
    });
};
```

And then wiring that up in the HTML like this:

```
<a ng-click='addCard(state)' ng-show='auth.user'>Add card</a>
```

Have a look at app.js and index.html over on https://github.com/puf/trenches, where you'll find a complete-but-minimal application.

Comment: I understand that, thanks! But, I still have no clue how to paste it into that specific json position, and I have no idea how to take the value from the input in the same div.

Comment: Unfortunately "I have no idea how to" is not really a question. I hoped pointing you to a working sample (and including the relevant markup and code in my answer) would be enough. But if not, you'll have to do better in your question. Click the edit link and ensure we have a minimal reproduction of where you are. It is probably a good idea to **also** set up a fiddle reproducing your problem and linking it in your question.